# Чем различаются параметры (в процедурах и функциях) с var и без var?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

объясните пожалуйста понятным языком, чем различаются параметры (в процедурах и функциях) с var и без var?

Comment: А просто кнопку [F1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)) на слове [**var**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)) нажать что мешает? `Most parameters are either value parameters (the default) or variable (var) parameters. Value parameters are passed by value, while variable parameters are passed by reference.`. Без **var** - вы передаёте только значение, т.е. при его изменении в процедуре - в основной программе значение не меняется. При использовании **var** - изменения параметра в процедуре передаются в основную программу.

Comment: @Alekcvp запостите как ответ и добавите уточнение про ссылочные типы? ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Не вижу смысла, вопрос полностью описан в справке по Delphi, даже с примерами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В справке написано ([Parameters: Value and Variable Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters)):

> Most parameters are either value parameters (the default) or variable (var) parameters. Value parameters are passed by value, while variable parameters are passed by reference.

В двух словах - Без var вы передаёте только значение, т.е. при его изменении в процедуре, в основной программе значение не меняется. При использовании var - изменения параметра в процедуре вернутся в основную программу.

Обратите внимание, что это касается только простых типов (числа, строки, record). Объекты и массивы по сути и так есть указатели. Также, если var, то передаваемое значение должно быть присваиваемым (т.е. переменной, а не результатом вычисления)

Comment: Ещё можно рассматривать аргумент без var как копию (что и делается в некоторых случаях)